# Java: convert PDF to image using ghost4j

Tags: java, image, pdf, ghost4j

I am trying to use the `ghost4j` library to convert a pdf to image. My code looks like this:

```
import org.ghost4j.document.*;
import org.ghost4j.renderer.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
.
.
.

        PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
        document.load(new File("M:\\test.pdf"));
        SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();
        renderer.setResolution(300);
        List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);
```

but I get the following error:

> error: cannot find symbol
>                   List images = renderer.render(document);
>                        ^   symbol:   class Image   location: class ImageRead 1 error

which indicates that compiler cannot find symbol "Image". I'm not sure why?